# ASP MVC 5 Identity 2: Cannot Determine how to Reference Custom role properties to User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, role

I am using MVC 5 with Identity 2. I have created two roles, one for administrators, and one for vendors. The problem I have is that the registration form must use properties that are defined in the vendor role. I cannot figure out how to make MVC use those role properties for register purposes. I've tried assigning the appropriate role to the applicationuser but, after assigning it the role it still says it doesn't exist. Is there anyway of doing this, or am I going to have to split this into two register screens (ie one to handle initial user creation and a second one to handle role specific implementation)?

```cs
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterVendorViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email, 
                    Email = model.Email,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                    CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                    Address = model.Address,
                    City = model.City,
                    State = model.State,
                    PostalCode = model.PostalCode
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
```

UPDATE: I split the views, the first view deals solely with the creation of the Application User, while the second view is where I add the VendorUser Role fields to the user created in the first view. It now errors, and says that I am not able to add VendorUserRole attributes to IdentityUserRole.

Error Code "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Project1.Models.VendorUserRole' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole'"

I clearly failed to update or override something in my roles implementation. Does anyone have any idea of where this can be fixed? I thought I altered all of them to work properly.

```cs
        // POST: /Account/RegisterP2
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterP2([Bind(Include = "Id")]RegisterPart2ViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var vendorUser = new VendorUserRole()
                {
                    Id = model.Id,
                    CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Address = model.Address,
                    City = model.City,
                    State = model.State,
                    PostalCode = model.PostalCode,
                };

                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(vendorUser.Id);
                **user.Roles.Add(vendorUser);**
```

UPDATE: I clearly need more understanding of Identity, before I try any more code; can someone tell me if my basic premise is correct?:

I need two different users: vendors and administrators which have different properties, I have one user class ApplicationUser which came with Identity 2. I have created roles with the different properties for each, and am now stuck. I cannot figure out how to reference the different roles to the main user class. According to my research in .NET a user is simply the entity that logs in, out, etc. Properly defined roles are supposed to allow you to attach the roles to a user instance, thereby creating the necessary role.

I hope I have not done hours of coding based on a faulty premise...

Comment: If anyone knows where I can find some resources about adding attributes to an identity 2 user using roles; I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because before the user registers, his user is not yet created, therefore his not-yet-existent user cannot have a role. You should have two separate views, using the same models and controllers, but you should be aware the user does not exist yet.

Comment: I know that is a solution, I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to do it all on one registration page.

Comment: It is possible, but messy. I am not recommending it.

Comment: Any idea what I missed that is causing the new error?